# how to find an specific character in a string

Tags: c#

In c#, how can I find a specefic character in a string. this "2222+2222" is my string and I want to find the character "+" in it? I want a function that returns a bool if it finds it.

Comment: Try [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx). Also, that was pretty easily Googleable.

Comment: `-3` Poor Effort on the OP's Part come on this one of all things should not be rocket science

Comment: -1 If you had Googled the question you would have found that IndexOf is the answer to your question as the very first link.  Please, try a little harder next time.

Answer (score 5):

string.Contains("+") returns a bool.

Answer (score 3):

`yourString.IndexOf("+")` will return 0 or a positive number if the character is found

Since you prefer something that returns bool, you can use `Contains` instead but notice that `Contains` does not provide an overload to perform a case-insensitive search. In scenarios where this is important (finding a string without caring for case), it's best to use `IndexOf(stringToSearch,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` to determine whether the string is found or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "2222+2222";

if (s.Contains("+")) {
  // dosomething...
}
```